# Let $ F = VN $ that $ V \cap N = 1 $ . Let $ L = N_{G}(V) $. $ (\vert N \vert , \vert F/N \vert) = $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $ G $ be a soluble group and $ A $ be a minimal normal subgroup of $ G $,where $ A $ is an elementary abelian group of prime power order. Let each chief factor of $ G/A $ has order $ 4 $ or a prime and $ A $ is the unique minimal normal subgroup of $ G $. Let N = Fit(G). then $ N = O_{p}(G) $. Let $ F/N = O_{p^{\prime}}(G/N) $, then $ F>N $. Let $ F = VN $ that $ V \cap N = 1 $ . Let $ L = N_{G}(V) $.

$ (\vert N \vert , \vert F/N \vert) = $ ?

$ V \in Syl_{p}(N) $?

Comment: $N$ is a $p$-group and $F/N$ is a $p'$-group so $(|N|,|F/N|)=1$. The statement $V \in {\rm Syl}_p(N)$ is nonsense because $V$ is a $p'$-group and $V$ is not even a subgroup of $N$.

Comment: What by Frattini argument yields $ G = LN $ ?

Comment: The complements of $N$ in $F$ are all conjugate in $F$ by Schur-Zassenhaus, so the Frattini argument applied to $F$ yields $G = N_G(V)F = N_G(V)VN = N_G(V)N$.